# connect 3 different true statements to an IF ELSE

Tags: javascript

I want return true if the number is an integer with 4 or 6 digits. no decimals or letter allowed
The thing is not working is the if its really a number check and if its got a decimal.

i think i got already the right functions applied to it but i just cant connect them properly to my if statement.
so i want to check if 3 different things a true then return true but didnt figured out

Please if possible **only answer** with a **hint** or a **link** or **SUDO Code** or *stuff i can look up*.
gonna answer the question myself when i figured it out

JS

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
   var result = (pin - Math.floor(pin)) !== 0; 
   if( pin.length === 4 || isNaN(pin) || result) {
     return true
   } else if ( pin.length === 6 || isNaN(pin) || result) {
     return true
   } else return false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "_only answer with a hint or a link or SUDO Code or stuff i can look up_" That's not an option as it would defeat the whole purpose of the site. (Which is to contain answers that are useful to people _beyond_ the person asking.)

Comment: u totally right sorry

Answer (score 1):

A simple regular expression can be used to test that is is 4 or 6 numbers.

```js
function isValidPin (pin) {
   return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin.toString());
}

console.log(isValidPin(123));
console.log(isValidPin("1234"));
console.log(isValidPin("12345"));
console.log(isValidPin("123456"));
console.log(isValidPin("1234567"));
console.log(isValidPin("12.45"));
console.log(isValidPin("12e45"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the conditions with the AND operator (&&).

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
   var result = (pin - Math.floor(pin)) !== 0; 
if( pin.length === 4 && isNaN(pin) && result) 
  { return true} else if ( pin.length === 6 && isNaN(pin) && result)  {
  return true
  
} else return false
  
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your or to and

```
 function validatePIN (pin) {
     //return true or false
      var result = (pin - Math.floor(pin)) !== 0; 
     if( pin.length === 4 && isNaN(pin) && result) 
     { return true} 
     else if ( pin.length === 6 && isNaN(pin) && result)  {
     return true
    } else return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty this:

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  var parsed = Math.parseInt(pin, 10);

  // if it's not an integer
  if(pin !== parsed.toString()) return false;

  return pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this. You should use regular expression for simplicity.

```js
console.log(445584, validatePin(445584));
console.log("445584", validatePin("445584"));
console.log("alj454", validatePin("alj454"));
console.log(4455.84, validatePin(4455.84));

function validatePin(pin){
  return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps I'm mistaken - but you could just check if the length is 4 OR 6, and continue your other two checks:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
    //return true or false
    var result = (pin - Math.floor(pin)) !== 0; 
    if(!isNaN(pin) && (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) && result) {
        return true
   } else return false
}
```

I've also edited your code, as it seemed illogical returning true for NaN.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into using `isNaN()` to detect if there are any characters that aren't numbers.

Also, using `.toString()` so you can check the `.length`.